# Search tags by text which contain other tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

The following code shows that `BeautifulSoup.find(text=)` will not search for tags which contain some other tags.

I am not sure if there is a way to do so.

Could anybody let me know whether there a way to perform such a search?

Thanks.

```
$ cat main.py 
#!/usr/bin/env python
# vim: set noexpandtab tabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=-1 fileencoding=utf-8:

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys
import re
soup = BeautifulSoup(sys.stdin.read(), 'html.parser')
print soup.find('td', text = re.compile(sys.argv[1]))

$ cat main.sh 
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# vim: set noexpandtab tabstop=2:

set -v
./main.py 'Overall design' <<EOF
<td nowrap="">Overall design<b>xxx</b></td>
EOF

./main.py 'Overall design' <<EOF
<td nowrap="">Overall design</td>
EOF

$ ./main.sh 
./main.py 'Overall design' <<EOF
<td nowrap="">Overall design<b>xxx</b></td>
EOF
None

./main.py 'Overall design' <<EOF
<td nowrap="">Overall design</td>
EOF
<td nowrap="">Overall design</td>
```

Comment: You  might want to add the [tag:python] tag with this post.